# How long does it take for new Tefillin straps to become "worked in" (i.e. soft, compliant, etc)?

Tags: tefilin

I just had to replace my "shel Rosh" Tefillin straps. Obviously they are stiff as can be! I forget how long it took for the last new strap I purchased to become soft and compliant. Does anyone know/remember/can hazard an educated guess how long it takes? Many thanks. Shabbat Shalom. Yom HaAtzmaut Sameach!

Comment: Probably depends how long you wear them and how much you sweat.

Comment: Also could depend on quality of the straps.